# Personal Portfolio (freeCodeCamp Responsive Web Design project)

Tags: html, css

I would appreciate som feedback on my fictional portfolio. I am doing the freeCodeCamp curriculum and a [personal portfolio](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/responsive-web-design-projects/build-a-personal-portfolio-webpage) is one of the Responsive Web Design Projects using only HTML/CSS.

I am especially interested in feedback regarding best practice, naming conventions and efficient code.

---

The code is also [on GitHub](https://oyvind-solberg.github.io/fcc-personal-portfolio/).

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4dd9b52bee.js"></script>
        <title>FunkzWeb</title>
    </head>
    <body>          
        <nav id="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <p><strong>Funkz</strong>Web</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="flex-row">
                    <li><a href="#welcome-section">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <section id="welcome-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header-text">
                    <p class="sub-heading">Hello!</p>
                    <h1><strong>I am Funkz</strong>Web</h1>
                    <p>Creative Digital Powerhouse</p>
                </div>
                <div class="center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Hire me now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="projects">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Projects</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="project-container">
                <div class="project-tile center">
                    <a
                        href="https://oyvindsen84.github.io/fcc-technical-document-page/"
                        target="_blank"
                    >
                        <div class="project-text center">
                            <h3>Technical Documentation Page</h3>
                        </div>
                        <img
                            src="img/project-01.jpg"
                            alt="Technical Documentation Page"
                        />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="project-tile center">
                    <a
                        href="https://oyvindsen84.github.io/fcc-product-landing-page/"
                        target="_blank"
                    >
                        <div class="project-text center">
                            <h3>Product Landing Page</h3>
                        </div>
                        <img
                            src="img/project-02.jpg"
                            alt="Product Landing Page"
                        />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="project-tile center">
                    <a
                        href="https://oyvindsen84.github.io/fcc-survey-form/"
                        target="_blank"
                    >
                        <div class="project-text center">
                            <h3>Survey Form</h3>
                        </div>
                        <img src="img/project-03.jpg" alt="Survey Form" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="project-tile center">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <div class="project-text center">
                            <h3>Personal Portfolio</h3>
                        </div>
                        <img
                            src="img/project-04.jpg"
                            alt="Personal Portfolio"
                        />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="contact">
            <div class="container center">
                <h2>Interested in working with us?</h2>
                <p>Let's Talk Now!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Hire me now</a>
                <div class="icons flex-row">
                    <a
                        id="profile-link"
                        href="https://github.com/Oyvindsen84"
                        target="_blank"
                        ><span class="fab fa-github"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-facebook"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-twitter"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></span></a>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fab fa-instagram"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <footer>
            <div class="container center">
                <div class="brand">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <p><strong>Funkz</strong>Web</p>
                    </div>
                    <p>Creative Digital Powerhouse</p>
                </div>              
                <p>
                    <small>&copy; 2019 FunkzWeb all rights reserved</small>
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
/* Color Schemes */
:root {
    --bg-light: #ffffff;
    --bg-dark: #222222;
    --text-dark-strong: #000000;
    --text-dark-normal: #8d8d8d;
    --text-light-strong: #ffffff;
    --text-light-normal: #aaaaaa;
    --text-weak: #888888;
    --style-dark: #333333;
    --style-dark-grey: #5c5c5c;
    --style-grey: #777777;
    --style-light-grey: #afafaf;
    --style-light: #dadada;
}

/* Basic Reset */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Basic setup */
body {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;

    color: var(--text-dark-normal);
    background-color: var(--bg-light);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    line-height: 1;

    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;

    padding-bottom: 2rem;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: var(--text-dark-strong);
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;

    color: var(--text-dark-strong);
}

li {
    display: block;

    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;

    color: var(--text-dark-normal);
}

strong {
    color: var(--text-dark-strong);
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

/* Utility Classes */
.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 4rem;
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
}


.center {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    text-align: center;
}

.header-text {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;

    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}

/* Buttons */
.btn {
    display: block;

    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: var(--text-light-strong);
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: var(--bg-dark);
}

/* Navbar */
#navbar {
    font-weight: 700;

    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 100%;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    border-color: var(--style-light);
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
    background-color: var(--bg-light);
}

#navbar .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#navbar a {
    display: block;

    padding: 1rem 1rem;
}

#navbar a:hover {
    color: var(--text-light-strong);
    background-color: var(--bg-dark);
}

.logo {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* Welcome Section */
#welcome-section {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 25vh 0 25vh 0;

    background: no-repeat url("../img/showcase-img.jpg") center / cover;
}

#welcome-section .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.sub-heading {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1;
;

    text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* Projects Section*/
#projects {
    padding: 3rem 0;
}

.project-container {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-rows: 350px;
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.project-tile {
    position: relative;

    overflow: hidden;
}

.project-tile .project-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    display: flex;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem;

    transition: all 0.5s;

    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.project-tile .project-text h3 {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transform: scale(0);

    color: var(--text-light-strong);
}

.project-tile a:hover .project-text {
    transform: scale(1);

    opacity: 1;
}

.project-tile a:hover .project-text h3 {
    transform: scale(1);
}

/* Contact Section */
#contact {
    padding: 3rem 0;
}

#contact h2 {
    padding: 0;

    text-transform: initial;
}

#contact p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#contact .btn {
    margin: 2rem 0;
}

#contact .container {
    flex-direction: column;
}

.icons {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.icons a {
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.icons a:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}


/* Footer */
footer {
    padding: 3rem 0;

    color: var(--text-light-normal);
    background-color: var(--bg-dark);
}

footer .container {
    flex-direction: column;
}

footer strong {
    color: var(--text-light-strong);
}

footer .brand {
    line-height: 1.2;

    margin-bottom: 2rem;
} 

footer .brand > p {
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}




/* Media queries desktop first */

/* Desktop 1800px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1800px) {
    .project-container {
        -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    }
}

/* Desktop 1200px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .project-container {
        -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}

/* Tablet 768px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .project-container {
        -ms-grid-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 4rem;
    }
    .header-text {
        font-size: 1.5rem;

        letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
    .sub-heading {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}

/* Phone 568px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    body {
        line-height: 1.2;
    }
    #navbar ul {
        display: none;
    }
    .container {
        padding: 0 1rem;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 2rem;

        padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    #contact h2 {
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }
    .header-text {
        font-size: 1.2rem;

        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }
    .sub-heading {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
    #projects,
    #contact {
        padding: 1.5rem 0;
    }
    footer {
        padding: 1rem 0;
    }
    footer .brand {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    .project-container {
        grid-auto-rows: 275px;
    }
}

@media (hover: none) {
    .project-tile .project-text {
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;

        display: block;

        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5rem 1rem;

        transform: translateY(-100%);

        opacity: 1;
    }
    .project-tile .project-text h3 {
        font-size: 1.3rem;

        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, great work! Your code looks good to me. Especially the CSS looks well structured. It's good to organize your code like you did with the comments. Just one little nitpicky thing: Why is z-index on #navbar 100? Wouldn't z-index of 1 have done the job as well?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it would. The reason I used the value 100 is just to keep the navbar always on top in case I decided to add more elements with a Z-index in the future.

Answer (score 1):

CSS vars are great to use if we want to create a shortcut to a more complex property value, so that we don’t have to remember it. CSS properties, like `box-shadow`, `media` query, `transform`, `font` and other CSS rules with multiple parameters are perfect examples. We can place the property in a variable so that we can reuse it via a more human readable format.

And so I think you can define these variables when using `media` query. Because I see you are using `@media` query in your code it would be nicer when use variables if you want.

```
:root {
    --bg-light: #ffffff;
    --bg-dark: #222222;
    --text-dark-strong: #000000;
    --text-dark-normal: #8d8d8d;
    --text-light-strong: #ffffff;
    --text-light-normal: #aaaaaa;
    --text-weak: #888888;
    --style-dark: #333333;
    --style-dark-grey: #5c5c5c;
    --style-grey: #777777;
    --style-light-grey: #afafaf;
    --style-light: #dadada;
    --bp-lg-desktop: 'only screen and (max-width: 1800px)';
    --bp-desktop: 'only screen and (max-width: 1200px)';
    --bp-tablet: 'only screen and (max-width: 768px)';
    --bp-mobile: 'only screen and (max-width: 568px)';
}

/*for example change this block
 Desktop 1200px */
@media var(--bp-desktop) {
    .project-container {
        -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    }
}
```